# Multi line of text field returns null value in search rest call

Tags: search, multiline-text-field

I have custom list in sharepoint online which contains 2 multi line of text fields (Rich text). I want to search content of any of the two field, for that I have written following call:

```
https://xxx/_api/search/query?querytext='*software*+Site:https://xxx/Lists/DemoList/'
```

By above call, I'm able to get proper result but I'm not able to display column values because rest call returns null value for multi line of text field.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The call is correct but previously I was trying with list columns but when I try with site columns and content type then it is works for me.

After creating site column and content type we can find our columns in "Search Schema". Here are the steps:

1. Open Site Settings
2. Click on "Search Schema" under "Site Collection Administration"
3. Search with your column name "Address"
4. It will be display result of column with "AddressOWSMTXT"
5. The same column name which we found, have to use in search call to display multi line column value.

Do the same for all type columns like choice column, datetime, yes/no, etc.